# How can I fit "ol.Map" to "Ext.panel.Panel"?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, mvvm, openlayers-3

I'm developing a web gis with `Extjs 6.0` and `OpenLayers 3.6.0` in MVVM Architecture. I want to put `ol.map` to a `Ext.panel.Panel`. Main view of the Project is as bellow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp2.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'MyApp2.view.main.MainController',
        'MyApp2.view.main.MainModel'
    ],
    xtype: 'app-main',
    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            bind: {
                title: '{name}'
            },
            region: 'west',
            html: 'its me! - West Panel',
            width: 125,
            minWidth: 100,
            maxWidth: 250,

        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            collapsible: false,
            html: '<div id="map" class="map"></div>',
            listeners: {
                beforerender: 'beforerender',
                afterrender: 'afterrender'
            }
        }]
});
```

first I render the `panel` with `html` config: `<div id="map" class="map"></div>` and then in `afterrender` listener initialize `ol.map` as follow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp2.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    requires: [
        'Ext.window.MessageBox'
    ],
    alias: 'controller.main',
    afterrender: function() {
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: "Global Imagery",
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms?service=WMS',
                        params: {LAYERS: 'world:worldRaster', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
                    })
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [35, 41],
                zoom: 4
            })
        });
    },
    beforerender: function(){
        console.log("Salam Bar Mahdi");
    }
});
```

The code does not give any error, but when I run it, Everything is good except when I want to zoom in map, it zoom another place. see following picture:
[image]
This bug remains stable until in `index.html` file I define follow `css`:

```
<style>
.map {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
</style>
```

This `css` put `ol.map` to a `600x600` box, But I want `ol.map` fit to `Ext.panel.Panel`.

**How do I do?**

Comment: Provide some documentation links!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? http://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: In your after render handler, after you have declared your map variable can you not just set the map height and width based on the panel dimensions? The panel is usually passed in as the first param to the afterrender eventually. I have done similar things when using Google maps, google maps api also lets you fire a resize event to tell it to size based on its containing element, such as the panel in your example. Can you do a similar thing here with the OL api?

Comment: Thanks for your response, `ol.map` must init with `afterlayout` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ol.map` class must sit in a certain height and width component. The only thing that is required is that initial `ol.map` with `afterlayout` event.

Comment: I am having similar issue but I don't understand your solution. What to do in `afterlayout` event?

Comment: Create `ol.map` inside `afterlayout` handler. The `panel` must first be configured and then map instance sit on it.

Comment: look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150227/how-define-new-geoext-panel-map-with-openlayers-3-6-0-and-extjs-6-0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `boxready` event of `Ext.Container` on version 4.2, as suggested in [this answer on GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/170725/62576), where the following code is proposed:

```
th.items = [
    Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;
            th.mapContainerId = me.id;
            me.on("boxready", function () {
                th.initMap();
            });
            me.on("resize", function () {
                if (th.mapInst) {
                    th.mapInst.updateSize();
                }
            });
            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    })
];
```

Comment: @trincot, thank you for your suggestions, I am new to writing asnwers here and, I have pure English